# Выскакивает командная строка приложения, когда открываю его

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, exe

Скомпилировал python в exe файл. Теперь когда открываю его, вместе с самим приложение открывается его командная строка, закрывая которую закрывается и само приложение. Как это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pyinstaller -w
```

Ключ `-w` будет запускать без окна консоли

---

для `cx_Freeze` нужно указать параметр `base = "Win32GUI"`

```
exe = [cx_Freeze.Executable("myGame.py", base = "Win32GUI")]
```

Comment: я пользовался cx freeze, тогда что писать?

Comment: дополнил ответ, посмотрите